# python sqlite - database loaded in to memory (RAM)?

Tags: python, sqlite, ram

I am thinking about using the sqlite3 library in python to do some data storage. It's important to me to avoid loading too much data into memory - there is potentially many (10+) gigabytes of data, and I want to be able to access it in such a way that the data isn't loaded into RAM all at once. Will sqlite3 accomplish this for me? I am thinking of the following code specifically:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''SELECT * FROM table1''')

var = c.fetchall()
```

Suppose that `example.db` takes up 14 gb, and `table1` takes up 1 gb. How much data would be loaded into RAM?

Comment: That's going to be up to your OS.

Comment: What is preventing you from trying it and checking actual memory consumption ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to use `fetchall()`, that *will* load your entire table into RAM, plus whatever housekeeping is required, so “more than 1 GB” is the answer to your question. Use `fetchone()` instead.

Comment: So to be clear - in your situation, nothing is loaded into RAM prior to the `fetchone()` command? Nothing is loaded at `conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')` or `c.execute("stuff")`?

Comment: No, clearly there's going to be *some* memory use prior to the `fetchone()` call, and it may well be the case that `fetchone()` does some buffering so that it's using more than one row's worth of data each time, but `fetchone()` is radically more memory-efficient than `fetchall()`. I have a 650MB database that's essentially all in one table. A `fetchall()` uses about 2GB of memory. A `fetchone()` causes no appreciable increase in memory use.